# pandas expanding (cummulative) value_counts

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to get the value counts up to each row in a dataframe?

```
|f1|f2|
-------
v1 | a  value_counts -> {a:1}
v2 | a  value_counts -> {a:2}
v3 | b  value_counts -> {a:2,b:1}
v4 | c  value_counts -> {c:1,a:2,b:1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `cumsum` on the output of `get_dummies` on the column of interest:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df["f2"])
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  1
>>> pd.get_dummies(df["f2"]).cumsum()
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  2  0  0
2  2  1  0
3  2  1  1
```

If you want the equivalent of `normalize=True` for value_counts, you can simply do it manually:

```
>>> x = pd.get_dummies(df["f2"]).cumsum()
>>> x.div(x.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
          a         b     c
0  1.000000  0.000000  0.00
1  1.000000  0.000000  0.00
2  0.666667  0.333333  0.00
3  0.500000  0.250000  0.25
```

This is probably the best format for further data processing. While you *could* force this into a dict-like format, pandas doesn't have good support for non-scalar elements, and so apart from being slow it can lead to mysterious bugs.  That said:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df["f2"]).cumsum().apply(dict, axis=1)
0    {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
1    {'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
2    {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}
3    {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}
dtype: object
```

Comment: how to normalize the first answer?

Comment: Define "normalize".

Comment: each cell in a row / sum of row

Comment: same way as value_counts does